# addPropertyReference cannot be applied to abstractBeanDefinition

Tags: java, spring

Im trying to construct beans at runtime based on entries in a config file.

I have a class that implements `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`, and in the `postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry` I have the following code

```
for (DataSourceConfig dsc : configuration.getDatabase()) {
        AbstractBeanDefinition jdbcTemplateDefinition = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition("com.me.threads.RemoteDataCollector")
                .addPropertyReference("remoteDBDoa",
                        BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition("com.me.db.RemoteDBDoa")
                                .addPropertyValue("jdbcTemplateRemote",
                                        BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition("org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate")
                                                .addPropertyValue("dataSource",
                                                        BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(DriverManagerDataSource.class)
                                                                .addPropertyValue("driverClassName", dsc.getDriverClassName())
                                                                .addPropertyValue("url", dsc.getUrl())
                                                                .addPropertyValue("username", dsc.getUsername())
                                                                .addPropertyValue("password", dsc.getPassword())
                                                                .getBeanDefinition()
                                                )
                                        .getBeanDefinition()
                                )
                        .getBeanDefinition()





        String name = BeanDefinitionReaderUtils.registerWithGeneratedName(jdbcTemplateDefinition, registry);
        jdbcTemplateBeanNames.put(dsc.getName(), name);

    }
```

There is an issue somewhere within this code that i cnt seem to find. 
Is this the right way to accomplish what i want or is there a better way?

Comment: What is the issue you have?

Comment: addPropertyReference cannot be applied to abstractBeanDefinition

Comment: Fairly new to this, still learning the Spring way of things

Comment: Please add the description to  your question instead of the comment.

Comment: Well `AbstractBeanDefinition` doesn't have a `addPropertyReference` method. The `BeanDefinitionBuilder` however does have it, so not sure why you are downcasting to an `AbstractBeanDefinition`.

Comment: I have changed it to BeanDefinitionBuilder yet still get the same error referencing the AbstractBeanDefinition.

Comment: I suggest to restructure your code, use temp variables to assign properties instead of all the nesting, that only works confusing.

Comment: The reason I used the AbstractBeanDefinition is cause I needed to use BeanDefinitionReaderUtils.registerWithGeneratedName so that each bean has a unique name. I have now split the code assigning it to temp vars yet now with registering it Im bait stuck.

Comment: I have casted it to AbstractBeanDefinition and the code runs. Yet the properties doesn't get assigned. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: `addPropertyReference` only works with a `String` if you pass anything else in there it will be converted to a `String` instead of the actual bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would refactor the code to the following

```
for (DataSourceConfig dsc : configuration.getDatabase()) {

        BeanDefinitionBuilder datasourceDef = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(DriverManagerDataSource.class);
        datasourceDef.addPropertyValue("driverClassName", dsc.getDriverClassName());
        datasourceDef.addPropertyValue("url", dsc.getUrl());
        datasourceDef.addPropertyValue("username", dsc.getUsername());
        datasourceDef.addPropertyValue("password", dsc.getPassword());

        BeanDefinitionBuilder jdbcTemplateDef = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.class);
        jdbcTemplateDef.addPropertyValue("dataSource", datasourceDef.getBeanDefinition());

        BeanDefinitionBuilder daoDef = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(com.me.db.RemoteDBDoa.class);
        daoDef.addPropertyValue("jdbcTemplateRemote", jdbcTemplateDef.getBeanDefinition());

        BeanDefinitionBuilder collectorDef = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(com.me.threads.RemoteDataCollector.class);
        collectorDef.addPropertyValue("remoteDBDoa", daoDef.getBeanDefinition());

        String name = BeanDefinitionReaderUtils.registerWithGeneratedName(collectorDefinition.getBeanDefinition(), registry);
        jdbcTemplateBeanNames.put(dsc.getName(), name);

    }
```

Which is clearer imho. I would probably move the construction of the `JdbcTemplate` to the DAO which would allow you to inject the `DataSource` into your DAO and which would save you messing around with an additional bean definition.

Comment: Changed to your code and have the same problem I get with mine. The remoteDBDoa isn't getting injected and when running the code I get a nullpointerexception

Comment: Then I doubt you copied it as is (I have no `addPropertyReference` anymore) or you aren't using the configured `RemoteDataCollector` instances.

Comment: Oops my fault, The problem was that there was code in the constructor calling the unassigned property. Thanx for the help was really useful

Comment: Ah well that isn't going to work, unless you use constructor injection instead of property based injection.

Comment: @PostConstruct was the solution